# миландр микросхема 5600ВЕ1У (нужен пример для SPI)

Tags: микроконтроллеры, ethernet, spi, миландр

Есть у кого пример работы с микросхемой миландра 5600ВЕ1У на SPI в связке с ве92(не обязательно с ним). Закупить предприятие успело данную микросхему. Надо код клепать. Чет пока не очень получилось. В частности запускается типо "дай бог" . Каретка приёмника не перемещается в начало (судя по RXBF_TAIL), хотя должна. Не всегда отправляется пакет. В общем пока разбираюсь. Но с примером было бы проще. А то в документации чет вообще не информативный пример.

Comment: А что это за микросхема вообще? На сайте её нет.

Comment: Её сняли с производства, но она у нас есть в проекте и её успели закупить. А так её сняли с производства и из-за санкций её скрыли с сайта